# What happened to the rest of the world?

Tags: plot-explanation, children-of-men

What I could catch from *Children of Men*:

- The UK is a relatively great place to be. The rest of the world has somehow gone to hell or something. Lots of refugees (or "fugees") go to the UK, where they are treated terribly.
- Julian and Clive mention that something bad happened in New York. ("Were your parents in New York when it happened? / Yeah. / Shit.")
- The art collector guy had to get works of art out of Madrid (or somewhere in Spain) before something bad happened.

My broad question is: What has happened to the rest of the world? (Nuclear apocalypse? Some epidemic? Or is everyone simply fighting because of the infertility problem --- and if so, why?)

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since I saw the movie, but [this description rings familiar](http://scienceline.org/2007/02/reel-science-children-of-men/):

> **Countries have been nuked, governments have collapsed, and societies
>   have descended into chaos.** Only Great Britain remains as a functioning
>   but authoritarian society that must deal with waves of desperate
>   refugees from the rest of the world.